# Purpose of building footprints

Tags: imagery, business, lidar, footprint

What are the uses (public and private industry) of building footprints?

I'm trying to figure out how polygon building footprints can be used.  i.e. are they used for determining tax liabilities, etc...

Comment: Taxation, Land Records, Web applications - NZ Building footprints - http://koordinates.com/layer/127-nz-building-footprints/

Comment: I'm not sure that buildings are used in taxation as much as the parcels that they reside on.  Most counties have tax parcels in cadastral datasets.  Building attributes are associated with the parcel, but not actually in the cadastral tax database.

Comment: @Roy, you are probably correct in your statement if you are specific to the United States.  A quick Google search shows a number of results in India where the area is part of the calculation of property tax.  Here is an example from [Delhi](http://www.mcdpropertytax.in/detail.php?id=10).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a number of places where footprints can come in very handy

**Public Sector:**

- **Taxation:**  As @Mapperz said, taxation is one area.  The percentage of
  property that is built on is sometimes used as a tax criterion.
- **Planning:**  Knowing where structures already exist on property can
  help in the planning process due to applied setbacks and minimum
  distances from houses and property lines.  Another example would be
  planning the location of a water line or a sewer line that needs to
  cross property on an easement.  If the footprint exists, the location
  constraints become more immediately obvious.
- **Public Works/Public Safety:**  Knowing where structures are located can
  show where access to the rear of property is constrained.  This can
  be important for public safety, if there is a fire, can a fire truck
  get to the back of a property, or is there not room between two
  structures.  From the public works perspective, if there is a
  facility running on an easement across a piece of property, knowing
  where vehicles can get in to be able to effect repairs is critical.

**Private Sector:**

In some ways, these mirror the public sector uses.  In a lot of cases, the public sector is creating data layers and then finds a benefit in exposing them to the public.  Here are some possible reasons why.

- **Planning:**  If someone wants to put in a new building, they can perform initial research to find where existing structures are that
  may constrain their plans.
- **Visualization/Simulation:**  If someone is trying to create a 3d model or fly-through of an area, doing extrusion on the building
  footprints vs the entire property, will give you a more
  representative simulation.
- **Analysis:**  Line of sight analysis for future development.  If you are designing a building having footprints will allows you to analyze
  more accurately what will or won't be visible.  This could also be
  useful for property valuation for sales purposes.
- **Suitability analysis:**  Example:  A solar panel contractor is evaluating an area for marketing purposes.  They take building
  footprints to see whether the majority of the residential structures
  are oriented in a way that makes them more suitable for a solar panel
  emplacement.  If there is not a high percentage, it is potentially
  not worth marketing in an area.

These are just a few ideas, but hopefully they give you some direction.

Answer (score 0):

LiDAR can be used to make 3-D representations of buildings (as well as building footprints).  These 3-D buildings can be used in viewsheds to model if a building will block a certain aesthetic feature.  They can also be used to [model shadows](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s4OhzaIXMhg).

Example:  You wouldn't want to build a new city park in an area that's perpetually in a building's shadow.